# Mystery notification icon in Ubuntu Software

Tags: software-center

(Please forgiven the probably-incorrect tag of "Software Center" - that app is obsolete, but it is more or less the predecessor of the current one, the one I'm having trouble with, so....)

I've installed 20.10 (over a previous 20.04 install) and now I get this mysterious notification icon at the top of "Ubuntu Software" application. At least I assume it's a notification of something or other. I can find no other info on it. Or on this app!

I thought maybe if I scrolled down thru the list apps, something would have another notification on it, but there is nothing.

Can anyone tell me how I can find out what, if anything, the system is trying to tell me? Any log file I can look at?

Thanks!

[image: The problem]

Answer (score 1):

The notification has appeared to show that the app has installed

Comment: Which app has installed? And why doesn't the notification go away? It's been there for days - weeks even.